# Issues after Upgrade Angular CLI 1.7.3 to 6.2.2

Tags: angular, webpack, angular6, production-environment, angular-cli-v6

I have upgraded Angular `5.2.0` project with CLI `1.7.3` to Angular `6.1.7` with CLI `6.2.2`.

Now when I run `ng build --prod`, I am getting below error.

```
ERROR in Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at normalizeBackSlashDirection (C:\workspace\appView\node_modules\webpack\lib\RequestShortener.js:16:17)
    at new RequestShortener (C:\workspace\appView\node_modules\webpack\lib\RequestShortener.js:26:15)
    at new Compiler (C:\workspace\appView\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:189:27)
    at Compiler.createChildCompiler (C:\workspace\appView\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:431:25)
    at Compilation.createChildCompiler (C:\workspace\appView\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:2429:24)
    at Object.pitch (C:\workspace\appView\node_modules\mini-css-extract-plugin\dist\loader.js:78:43)
```

How could I fix this?

Comment: Had this issue once. The problem probably was that the Angular and the CLI versions were incompatible. using `npm update` fixed it for me

Comment: witch version of webpack do you use?

Comment: @Andifined no luck with `npm update`

Comment: @fatemefazli version `4.19.0`

Answer (score 0):

try yo change your webpack, hope this helps:

```
npm remove webpack
```

then:

```
npm install webpack@4.11.1
```

or Remove your `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` Update webpack version in `package.json`
Run `npm install` again.

Comment: I don't have `webpack` in `package.json`. It's installing by `@angular-devkit/build-angular` or some other package.

Comment: @Bishan yes, but you can change the webpack version

Comment: Sure. I'll try this by adding `webpack@4.11.1` to `package.json`

Comment: No luck with that. Same issue again.

Answer (score -1):

***This happened because of a private variable declared in TS that you using in hTML***

Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

is this replace is private  so not able to read in HTML file

---

***Step to Update***

***Installing or Updating the Angular CLI to Version 6***

Updating the Angular CLI is easy and it's a matter of installing the latest version from npm using the following command:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

You may need to add sudo depending on your npm configuration.
Also it goes without saying that you need Node.js 8+ and NPM installed on your system to be able to install and run Angular CLI 6.

Updating Angular 5 CLI to Version 6 (Method 2)
You can also uninstall the previous Angular CLI 5 version before you install the latest version using the following command:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
```

Next run the npm install command globally:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Upgrading Angular 4|5 Projects

First, start by installing the Angular CLI 6 locally using the following command (Make sure you are inside your project's root folder):

```
npm install @angular/cli@latest
```

**Updating Configuration Files**
There are many differences between Angular 4|5 and Angular 6 such as
•   Angular 6 uses angular.json instead of angular-cli.json.
•   Different versions of dependencies in package.json etc.

You can update different configuration files automatically by running the following command from the project's root folder:

```
ng update @angular/cli
```

Discovering Packages to Update
Angular CLI has a new utility that allows you to automatcially analyze your project's package.json file and displays dependencies that need to be updated.

Using you terminal from the root folder of your Angular 5 project run the following command:

```
ng update
```

This is an example output from this command:

Upgrading Core Packages to Angular 6
Now you need to update the core packages/dependencies to Angular 6. Simply run the following command:

```
ng update @angular/core
```

Upgrading RxJS
You can update RxJS using the ng update command:

```
ng update rxjs
```

First check your versions of installed Angular CLI and other dependencies with:

```
ng --version
```